# Vertical align Bootstrap 4 .close icon inside Alert

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, font-size

I'm using the Bootstrap 4 [Close icon](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/close-icon/) inside an Alert.

```
   <div class="alert alert-info p-2">
       <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">×</a>The CVC card code is required.
   </div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/4ImkAPOKug

[image]

The problem is that the close icon is not vertically centered within the anchor element. I would like to move it up a few pixels. When inspecting the `.close` CSS, I see that `line-height:1` controls the height of the anchor, so adjusting `line-height` shrinks the height of the anchor, but I prefer to keep it as is for consistency.

Other than changing the `line-height`, is there a way to **vertically position the icon within the line-box of the anchor**? I've tried `display:inline-block`, `vertical-align:middle`, bottom margin, etc... but nothing seems to work. I don't want to vertical center within the alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to get the standard `close` to align to the top properly. A workaround is to use `align-text-top small` to shrink the font and height of the `close` element.

```
<div class="alert alert-info p-2">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">
             <span class="align-text-top small">&times;</span>
        </a>
        The CVC card code is required
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/go/gr21OObdyV

Answer (score 2):

Not the best way, but you can apply a margin-top of `-0.15rem`

```css
.close {
 margin-top:-0.15rem;
}


/* To illustrate */
.alert {
  position:relative;
}
.alert:after {
 content:"";
 position:absolute;
 top:26px;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
 border-bottom:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row py-3">
    <div class="col-8">
      <div class="alert alert-info p-2">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">&times;</a>The CVC card code is required.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row py-3">
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="alert alert-info p-2">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">&times;</a>The CVC card code is required.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use *[baseline](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox_align-items_baseline)* to align the items by their baseline in a combination:

```css
.alert{
    display: flex;
    align-items: baseline;
}

.alert:after {
   content:"";
   position:absolute;
   top:31px;
   left:0;
   width:100%;
   border-bottom:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
   <div class="row py-3">
      <div class="col-6">
         <div class="alert alert-info p-2">
            <p>The CVC card code is required</p>
            <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">
            &times;
            </a>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
         <div class="alert alert-info p-2">
            <p>The &times; aligns toward the bottom of the anchor's line-box?</p>
            <a class="close align-top d-table-cell align-top" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">
            <span class="border border-danger">&times;</span>
            </a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox to align the close-button vertically:

```
<div class="alert alert-success fade show d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <i class="fa-duotone fa-circle-exclamation fa-lg me-auto"></i>
    <span class="me-auto px-3">This is a success alert ...</span>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert"></button>
</div>
```

[image]